# Gradle DSL method not found android()

Tags: android, gradle

I open a friend project at Android Studio, my AS version is greater than his. 
Here is the error:

```
Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:The project 'firstapp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file        The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin.
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'
}
dependencies {
}
```

How can i get this fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here from official doc.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

```
/**
 * The first line in the build configuration applies the Android plugin for
 * Gradle to this build and makes the android {} block available to specify
 * Android-specific build options.
 */

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: Now i get another error: Error:(2, 0) Cause: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
<a href="openFile:D:\APPS\Snap\andrtoid studio source code\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Use Java 7 instead of 8

Comment: Thanks, the project was using jdk 1.7 and i updated for 1.8